logback.xml or logback-spring.xml?
Hy, I work with various project using logback and springboot, and some use a logback.xml file , some use logback-spring.xml file.
What is the difference between the 2 ?
How to configure one being used instead of the other?

logback-spring.xml allows you to use Spring boot logback extensions.

You can read more here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/how-to/logging.html#howto.logging.logback

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
